# Update to 20.04.3 LTS broke samba

Tags: upgrade, samba

Yesterday I upgraded from 18.04 to current LTS.

When I now try to install samba I get the following:

```
[sudo] password for phill:  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies. <br />
samba : Depends: python3-samba but it is not going to be installed  
        Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10) but it is not going to be installed  
         Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not going to be installed  
         Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10) but it is not going to be installed  
         Recommends: samba-dsdb-modules but it is not going to be installed  
         Recommends: samba-vfs-modules but it is not going to be installed  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have attempted all the fixes I could find, but nothing helps.

I also notice that `gnome-control-center` does not work/install with a missing `libsmbclient` ...

any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt install -f`?

Comment: Did you not have samba installed before the upgrade?

Comment: OK, long arc is that while doing the upgrade I recall seeing some option(s) regarding samba - I took the default option! This may relate to the fact that there seemed to be a bionic library left behind.  Finally everything broke! So I did a fresh install of 20.04 and everything now works as expected.